# Wrong file icon

Tags: wine

[image]

I have installed Unity 3d Linux version, but the icon associated with the `.unitypackage` is not showing correctly. It always shows the wine icon. I have totally removed Wine, but the icon is still showing. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `file -b --mime-type FILENAME`?

Comment: application/gzip

Comment: How did you installed Unity 3D ? the mimetype is not correct; try asking in Unity3D forum

Comment: downloaded from http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/

Comment: Oh sorry, Mime type is : application/x-wine-extension-unitypackage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the file extension you can use:

`file -b --mime-type FILENAME`

in this case : `application/x-wine-extension-unitypackage`

After that, copy the icon you need to use to `/usr/share/icons/ICONTHEME` in the mimetypes folder with this file name `application-x-wine-extension-unitypackage`

Rebuild the icon cache using `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/ICONTHEME` and the new icon will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much, successfully changed the icon. anyway still need to fix the mime type, up-voted :)

Comment: The mime type is related to the application you're using; Pantheon files (File manager) just shows the icon associated to the mimetype, maybe Unty 3D is not saving the files correctly. Trying reporthing that upstream.